# Can ElasticSearch be used purely for aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

In my current usecase, I'm using ElasticSearch as a document store, over which I am building a faceted search feature.

The [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html) state the following:

> Sorting, aggregations, and access to field values in scripts requires a different data access pattern.
>
> Doc values are the on-disk data structure, built at document index time, which makes this data access pattern possible. They store the same values as the _source but in a *column-oriented fashion that is way more efficient for sorting and aggregations*.

Does this imply that the **aggregations are not dependent on the index**? If so, is it advisable to prevent the fields from being indexed altogether by setting **{"index": "no"}** ?

This is a small deviation, but where does the setting **enabled** come in? How is it different from **index**?

On a broader note, should I be using ElasticSearch if aggregations is all I'm looking for? Should I opt for other solutions like MongoDB? If so, what are the performance considerations?

HELP!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is definitely possible to use Elasticsearch for the sole purpose of aggregating data. I've seen such setups a few times. For instance, in one past project, we'd index data but we'd only run aggregations in order to build financial reports, and we rarely needed to get documents/hits. 99% of the use cases were simply aggregating data.

If you have such a use case, then you can tune your mapping to

The role of `enabled` is to decide whether your data is indexed or not. It is true by default, but if you set it to false, your data will simply be stored (in `_source`) but completely ignored by analyzers, i.e. it won't be analyzed, tokenized and indexed, and thus, it won't be searchable, you'll be be able to retrieve the `_source`, but not search for it. If you need to use aggregations, then `enabled` needs to be true (the default value)

The `store` parameter is to decide whether you want to store the field or not. By default, the field value is indexed, but not stored as it is already stored with the `_source` itself and you can retrieve it using source filtering. For aggregations, this parameter doesn't play any role.

If your use case is only about aggregations, you might be tempted to set `_source: false`, i.e. not store the `_source` at all since all you'll be needed is to index the field values in order to aggregate them, but this is rarely a good idea [for various reasons](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html#_disabling_the_literal__source_literal_field).

So, to answer your main question, aggregations do depend on the index, but the (doc-)values used for aggregations are written in dedicated files, whose inner structure is much more performant and optimal than accessing the data from the index in order to build aggregations.

If you're using ES 1.x, make sure to set [`doc_values`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html) to true for all the fields you'll want to aggregate on (except analyzed strings and boolean fields).

If you're using ES 2.x, `doc_values` is true by default, so you don't need to do anything special.

**Update:**

It is worth noting that aggregations are dependent on [doc_values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/doc-values.html) (i.e. [Per Document Values](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50DocValuesFormat.html) `.dvd` and `.dvm` Lucene files), which basically contains the same info as in the inverted index, but organized in a column-oriented fashion, which makes it much more efficient for aggregations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I still don't understand *how* aggregations are dependent on the index if they're using disk-level data structures.

Comment: An index IS composed of a set of [several disk-level data structures stored in files](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/package-summary.html#Overview) :-) Some of them are loaded into the heap, some are loaded in the file cache, but everything (including aggregations) is ultimately stored in a data structure located in one or more files.

Comment: That makes sense. Just to be clear, aggregations are dependent on the forward index, as opposed to the inverted index - which is for search. But both kinds of indices exist within the Segment Index. Sounds about right?

Comment: Aggregations are dependent on [doc_values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/doc-values.html) ([Per Document Values](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene50/Lucene50DocValuesFormat.html) `.dvd` and `.dvm` files), which is basically the same info as in the inverted index, but organized in a column-oriented fashion, which makes it much more efficient for aggregations.

Comment: Thanks a lot! ^_^ Also, would help if you could the edit answer to include the above info.